# How can a function with a long database query provide data globally to shinyServer()?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a ten second database query that should run on a remote server and load the data in the Global Environment for the shiny app to use.

The query is saved in a R file `get_SQL_data.R` that contains a single function: `get_data()`. It is in the same directory as `server.R` and `ui.R`. It returns a list of data objects from the `fetch()` command:

```
#Contents of get_SQL_data.R

library(RMySQL)
get_data <- function() {
  ...
  ...
  return(list(data1, data2)) # Returns from RMySQL `fetch()` command
}
```

Then in `server.R` I source the file outside of the `shinyServer()` function so it is supposed to run and fetch the data before `shinyServer()` runs:

```
source("get_SQL_data.R")
var <- get_data(wait = TRUE)
table_1 <- var[[1]]
table_2 <- var[[2]]

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  ...
  #Do stuff with table_1 and table_2 data
  ...
})
```

On my local machine I can simply run the function and store it in the global environment where `shinyServer()` can access it. But this approach isn't working in a remote server because I don't know how to create the Global Environment variables `data1` and `data2`.

Is there a better way to load Global Environment variables in memory on the remote shiny-server?

Also the database call takes about 10 seconds. How can I only have the `shinyServer()` function run only when the data is loaded in the global environment so I don't get the error: `"data1" is not available`?

Comment: What happens if you put the code inside the `shinyServer` function and add `local=TRUE` to `source`?

Comment: I just rooted into the remote server and installed R Studio Server. Can't answer this question. If others want the answer because they can't use RStudio Server than I hope it gets answered.

Comment: Also I fixed the original issue: the code has to go in the ui.R file, not the server.R file.

Comment: Also after about 800k rows this is ineffecient and need to optimize how you read data